# Spring Roo Single Form Multiple Submit valued by Id

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, spring-roo

I am using `JQuery` dialog to display a `<form:form>` to identify/select a particular record to be added from query. Every record in the table should contain a button as the `submit` trigger of the said form to add the selected record. The code below illustrate the structure of the code:

```
<form:form action="POST" action="form_action" modelAttribute="form">
    <div><form:hidden path="selectedDate" />
         <!-- Other components relating to the parent record -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- The detail of the parent -->
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${items}" var="itr">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${itr.name}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Select" name="${itr.id}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Is there a way to get a post parameter of `id` to indicate the selected record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the id and name of your submit button to be the proper Spring MVC input name, and make the value the proper selected ID value.  Something like this:

```
<form:form action="POST" action="form_action" modelAttribute="form">
    <div><form:hidden path="selectedDate" />
         <!-- Other components relating to the parent record -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- The detail of the parent -->
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${items}" var="itr" varStat="itrStat">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${itr.name}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="${itr.id}" name="form.items[${itrStat.index}]" id="form.items${itrStat.index}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

All Spring cares about is that the name posted in the Form matches some property on your Model Attribute defined in the Form tags and in the corresponding handler in your Controller.

Comment: Is there a way the value could be `Submit` instead of `${itr.id}`?

Comment: There are lots of ways to skin a cat.  However, making the button's value be "Submit" would mean that the backend would receive a value for the "form.items" with the value "Submit".  If you want the button to be still have that value (not sure why, but ok), then you will most likely have to have a hidden field, or maybe multiple hidden fields, and let that carry the value to the backend instead of the button, and just use the button to trigger the submit.